# How to create a function that reverses strings in a given list of string values without using list comprehensions

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'White', 'Black']
```

and I want it to output as follows:

```
['deR', 'neerG', 'eulB', 'etihW', 'kcalB']
```

How can this be done without using list comprehensions such as `[x[::-1] for x in string_list]`?
I already made my own version of code but I have to manually add new variables each time more keys are added in the list. Here it is:

```
OriginalLists=['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'White', 'Black']

strings1=''.join([str(item)for item in OriginalLists[0]])



strings2=''.join([str(item)for item in OriginalLists[1]])
strings3=''.join([str(item)for item in OriginalLists[2]])
strings4=''.join([str(item)for item in OriginalLists[3]])
strings5=''.join([str(item)for item in OriginalLists[4]])

a=(''.join(reversed(strings1)))
b=(''.join(reversed(strings2)))
c=(''.join(reversed(strings3)))
d=(''.join(reversed(strings4)))
e=(''.join(reversed(strings5)))

result=[a,b,c,d,e,f]
print(result)
```

I am a newbie at programming and knowing the answers to this would be very great to my experiences.

Comment: Can you tell us why you don't want to use list comperhension?

Comment: @VinsonCiawandy We have this python exercise that challenges us to not use list comprehensions and make our own code that reverses given strings in a list.

Comment: Use a for loop?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new list

```
result = []
```

iterate over each word in the original list

```
for word in OriginalLists:
```

and append the reversed word to the result list

```
    result.append(''.join(reversed(word)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simple and clear method:

```
OriginalLists=['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'White', 'Black']

for i in range(len(OriginalLists)):
    OriginalLists[i] = OriginalLists[i][::-1]
    print(OriginalLists)
```

We are simply iterating through the list, reversing each string (`[::-1]`), and printing out the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Without using loop :

```py
var = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'White', 'Black']
result = list(map(lambda x : x[::-1],var))
```

We apply lambda expression to reverse a stribg to each element of list.